# aws dsk error Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services

to list s3 bucket object using the JavaScript aws sdk on angular, 
i do :

```
s3.listObjectsV2({ Bucket: bucketName, Prefix: prefix, StartAfter: prefix + "/" }, function (err, resp) {
           if (err) { console.log(err) }
           else {
              console.log(resp.Contents);
           }
      });
```

i had this error :

> core.js:12584 ERROR TypeError: **Cannot convert undefined or null to
>   object
>       at hasOwnProperty** ()
>       at isEndpointDiscoveryApplicable (discover_endpoint.js:279)
>       at Request.discoverEndpoint (discover_endpoint.js:322)
>       at Request.callListeners (sequential_executor.js:102)
>       at Request.emit (sequential_executor.js:78)
>       at Request.emit (request.js:683)
>       at Request.transition (request.js:22)
>       at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (state_machine.js:14)
>       at state_machine.js:26
>       at Request. (request.js:38)

**UPDATE**

found the issue on github : https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/2347

i downgraded my aws-sdk libary from "2.353.0" to "2.351.0", to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this was a bug on the aws-sdk-js libary. it will be fixed in next version of the libary, the **aws-sdk-js 2.353.0**.

here is the bug [github](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/2347#issuecomment-438058214)